# How to stop/pause a wav file being played by a thread?

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, audio

I have created a thread dedicated for playing wav. The main thread is for the Win32 form GUI (VS 2010). When a stop or pause request is received, Ｉcan make use of the waveOutpause or waveOutClose functions. However, being just a bit more than a beginner in C++ programming, I am not quite sure how should I put the function in. I know that the above functions cannot be directly called from outside the thread for playing wav. Is there exists a simple solution?

Comment: What all have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

The main thread can use SetEvent/ResetEvent to control the WAV thread stop/go state. The WAV thread calls WaitForSingleObject (with 0 timeout) every time around its playing loop to sense the event state.

Similarly, you could use a second event to resume play after a pause. When the WAV thread calls WaitForSingleObject on a non-signaled event (with INFINITE timeout) the thread is suspended, waiting for the event to become signaled.

Comment: oh, it sounds cool. But I am using pthread( as taught in lecture) . Does there exist a similar way in pthread? Much thanks!!